# Can anyone suggest an Anti-malware app for Android?

Tags: android, antivirus, malware

I am aware of the fact that opinion based questions are not allowed, so I will tell you exactly what I expect from the app, and no vague terms like *best* or *good* will be used.

The app must have:

1. Recognize and eliminate a good fraction (more than 3/4th of all malware)
2. No ads
3. No side functions (please no CM Security)

I don't want the best app. But do please give me a list of all the ones that satisfy this condition and I'll take care of finding the app that suits me.

If this question doesn't meet the standards of this site, I am more than ready to improvise.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I browse heavily on android, and I sometimes accidentally click random clickbaits (I'm smart enough to not do that, but sometimes I accidentally tap around). I need sure ways to get rid of malware.

Comment: Currently I don't  use any anti-malware/ antivirus application on android , from experience with other platforms I would to believe Malware bytes anti-malware application is as good as it is on Desktop platform with a good success rate. What I like about this software it doesn't hide under the "antivirus"  tag as other applications do (it deals with malware primarily).  It is good when it cones to digging up malicious , adware, spyware or  potentially unwanted programs. However I can't recommend it now as I haven't used it in android. In any case you may want to try it :)

Comment: You might wish to check with my list of [Anti-Malware](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_antimalware#group_445) apps. Though it contains a lot of candidates, especially filter out those greedy for your data (watch out for the monitor icons) and those asking for too many permissions. The only thing I'm afraid of is: that won't leave many candidates. Those left will not carry "well-known names", and I'm not sure if they meet your terms. Most likely conclusion: chose between pest and cholera, or to cast out daemons by calling the devil… So better use an AdBlocker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to find a "free" Anti-Malware solution. I would recommend
Sophos Free Antivirus.

Here are the 3 reasons why:

1. It's actually free no nagging.
2. You decide how much security and resources you want to use.
3. Sophos has good reviews; check them out:
   https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/mobile-devices/android/january-2017/sophos-mobile-security-6.5-170118/